# How to install web app within my network, without using XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am creating a webpage using PHP, it is going to be used only in LAN. For some internal reasons I can not use XAMPP (I was going to use phpmyadmin as a tool for my database), so which would be the best way to do this by using PHP as a scripting language and MySQL for my database?

Is Ms Access Database one of the options?

Comment: if you don't want/need a web server, just run it as a command line with php-cli.

Comment: You can use IIS as a web server and PostgreSQL (or SQL Server) for database :)

Comment: What are the "internal reasons" you can't use XAMPP? That context might help us answer your question. MS Access probably isn't the tool you want, but it might work under certain conditions.

Comment: @Chris security reasons, my company doesn't find XAMPP so reliable, but also they dont want to pay for hosting the page, so I need to find a 'no cost' way, to deal with everything.